# Do tomes of jewelcrafting/blacksmithing drop in inferno mode?

Tags: diablo-iii

I assume that tomes of secrets start to drop in inferno mode; but do the other two types of tomes continue to drop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - Tomes of Secrets are the only Tome drops in Inferno. You'll need to use the Auction House or go back to Hell to get Tomes of Blacksmithing and Jewelcrafting.

Comment: So there is no crossover at all? (like the rares/magic items you get in Nightmare might still be crafted into Normal ingredients).

Comment: None for tome drops - where crafting materials are concerned, occasionally Act IV items salvage into materials for the next higher difficulty, while Act I items sometimes salvage into materials from the previous difficulty. It seems to be tied more to required level than where the item came from.